# OUTFILE Microsoft SQL Server equivalent?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there something like `INTO...OUTFILE` (from MySQL) in Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve (apart from getting some data out of your database and on to disk)? Your question is rather lacking detail, if you explain *why* you want this functionality it might help others answer you question. SQL Server has SSIS (DTS depending on earlier versions) to export data, will that not do what you want?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing here- DTS.  Didn't want to provide that answer though because the question left so much without explanation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This code causes the query results to be dumped into a text file.**

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell'bcp "SELECT TOP 5 CUSTOMERID FROM Northwind.dbo.Customers" queryout "c:\text.txt" -c -T -x'
```

**References:**

- [Code Samples](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/how-do-i-send-a-database-query-to-a-text-file.html)
- [BCP Utility Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)
- [xp_cmdshell Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx)

Comment: I was looking for something like this. I needed to export data from query itself.Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) or [osql (in SQL 2000)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214012%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx) to store the output from a command line outside of SSMS very like working with mysql from the command line. You just have to provide the correct parameters, including the query you want to run.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how fancy you want to get.  You can use [SSMS to generate a CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115054/how-to-get-export-output-in-real-csv-format-in-sql-server-managment-studio/6124874#6124874) A less user-friendly option is a [BCP export](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx).  Which I see @hamlin11 just suggested