# SQL - Create comma separated column without XML Path

Tags: sql-server-2008

Here is how my data looks currently

```
1  Inspection charge
1  Liftgate @ pickup
2  Inspection charge
2  Inside delivery
2  Inside pickup
```

I would like the data to look like below:

```
1  Inspection charge, Liftgate @ pickup
2  Inspection charge, Inside delivery, Inside pick up
```

The data is now showing up as a table, pls help. Also, XML Path does not work in my version of sql server.

Thanks.

Comment: See this SA question on exporting to CSV: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382846/exporting-data-from-sql-server-express-to-csv-need-quoting-and-escaping If that's not what you need, please rephrase your question.

Comment: You're using SQL Server 2008? What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: `for Xml` will work from `Sql server 2005`. You can use it in `Sql server 2008`. Check here for more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms178107.aspx

Comment: DON'T **EVER** PUT CSV DATA IN COLUMNS! If you need to format the results of a query differnetly, handle that in the client app.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn While you're right, I'm guessing that they want to select the data in a comma-separated list which is what `FOR XML` can be used for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE
  (
     id   INT,
     col1 VARCHAR(20)
  )
DECLARE @results TABLE
  (
     id        INT,
     commalist VARCHAR(max)
  )

INSERT INTO @table1
VALUES      (1,
             'Inspection charge'),
            (1,
             'Liftgate @ pickup'),
            (2,
             'Inspection charge'),
            (2,
             'Inside delivery'),
            (2,
             'Inside pickup')

DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX),
        @id      INT
DECLARE cur CURSOR static FOR
  SELECT DISTINCT id
  FROM   @table1

OPEN cur

FETCH cur INTO @id

WHILE ( @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 )
  BEGIN
      SELECT @listStr = COALESCE (COALESCE(@listStr+',', '') + col1, @listStr)
      FROM   @table1
      WHERE  id = @id

      INSERT INTO @results
      SELECT @id,
             @listStr

      FETCH cur INTO @id
  END

SELECT *
FROM   @results

CLOSE cur

DEALLOCATE cur
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I was able to get it to work with XML path.