# SQL Server Management Studio data extract with tabs

Tags: excel, ssms, data-extraction

One one of my projects I am currently working with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and came across the issue when saving file in `.csv` format. In particular some of the columns that I am extracting are of data type `nvarchar` and includes multiple lines within 1 cell.

When exporting data into a `.csv` file, Excel automatically drops the line no matter which delimiter I select (`,`, `tab`, or `|`). I assume this is due to `CHAR(13)` and/or `CHAR(10)` being present within some of the cells.

What already works for me is replacing `CHAR(10)/CHAR(13)` with some other characters but that is too much of the intervention into data integrity.

I was able to get what I need in SSRS tool, however given the large number of data i am wondering if there is a way to set up SQL Server Management Studio so it would "lock" cell contain and in case cell contains multiple lines/rows, it would still be shown in one cell.

I have tried a few articles on here and a few other resources but non of them seem to be answering this specific question.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you open the csv in a notepad?

Comment: In the notepad it does not seem to be dropping the line, but when copied from notepad into excel it does drop the line again.

Answer (score 1):

When you export the data from SSMS, putting quotes around the data from every string column will cause the data between delimiters to be treated as a single field of data.

In SSMS there's an option for this, in Tools -> Options -> Query Results -> SQL Server -> Results to Grid, it's called "Quote strings containing list separators when saving .csv results".

Sorry the above does not work for newline characters. I read a SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382846/exporting-data-from-sql-server-express-to-csv-need-quoting-and-escaping) which had some useful suggestions.

The most relevant being:

1. for a one of need, just cut an paste from SSMS to excel.
2. Use SSIS if you want to do it in a more automated way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Harvey. I had this option ticked initially so unless i need to do something specific after i re tick it, it does not work for me for some reason.

Comment: When you open the file with notepad, are the string fields surrounded by "  ?

Comment: Nope. Could that be because file is exported as .csv not .txt?

Comment: see extra bit to my answer above